# Laravel Eloquent get model by scope on associated model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model `Foo` which has a field `bar_id`. I define the relationship between them in the `Foo` model:

```
public function Bar()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\Bar');
}
```

The `Bar` model has a `baz_id`, and a scope to get all `Bar`s which have a particular `baz_id`. This is the scope in my `Bar` model:

```
public function scopeFromBaz($query, $bazId)
{
    return $query->where('baz_id', $bazId)
}
```

I now want to make a call of all `Foo`s where their associated `Bar` has a `baz_id` of `1`. How do I do this? I've tried:

```
Foo::where('bar', function($query) {
    $query->fromBaz(1);
});
```

But that produces the error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fromBaz()

Answer (score 2):

You have to use whereHas when you're adding conditions to relationships.

The query should be

```
Foo::whereHas('Bar', function ($query) {
    $query->fromBaz(1);
})->get();
```

See : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

I also spotted something on your other piece of code, you haven't added a return on your Bar function in the Foo model.

Comment: The return is not necessary.